# Removing header from json and leave json array

Tags: json, pandas

I have a json file in the form

```
{"total_rows":1000,"rows":[{data},{data},{data}]}
```

and I just want

```
[{data},{data},{data}]
```

I know pandas has desired output to dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd
file_reading = json.loads(open(url).read())
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_reading['rows'])
print(df)
```

But I am hoping for a way to do this outputting to json array and its a big dataset so I dont want to loop

Comment: Why are you using pandas if you just want to extract the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You opened a file without closing it. There's nothing fancy needed, the JSON just translate into a dictionary in Python:

```py
with open(url) as fp:
    file_reading = json.load(fp)

df = pd.DataFrame(file_reading["rows"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doesnt this return a data frame?

Comment: Yes. Isn’t that what pandas for?

Comment: yea right okay, so I was using pandas a (a bad) example. I want to remove the header from JSON and return JSON

Comment: then `return file_heading["rows"]` should be enough?

Comment: hahah too easy. Thanks